# How to read a text file line by line

Tags: rgb-led, led-strip

I am making an LED controller that reads instructions from a text file on my computer. I need to get the arduino to read this text file line by line and put each line into the appropriate variables. I'm using a sparkfun pro micro which is a knock off arduino pro micro. The pro micro is connected via USB

I've seen people use the SD library, but I don't know if this will work for my situation because I am reading directly from the computer and not an SD card. Is this the correct approach, or is there an additional/alternate library that I need to use?

Comment: You have Serial. That's all you have. Read the data, parse it. On the PC use some software to send the file (Putty, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

- Read character by character and copy it to a temporary buffer of the maximum length of one line.
- When you parsed an end of line symbol, you start parsing the (complete) line in the buffer.
- In this line parsing (preferably a separate function), you parse the line, using string to type conversion functions, like `atoi` (string to an inter) etc. Also you can use the C function `strtok` to split the string based on a symbol (e.g. comma).
- After parsing the line, clear the buffer (you already processed it), and continue filling the buffer again until it is full.
- Don't forget to check for end of file.

Comment: Can that be done through the SD library?

Comment: No. As I mentioned in my comment to your question, all you have is Serial. You can only read what something on the PC happens to send to the Arduino.

Comment: As Majenko says, only Serial. The SD library (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileRead) has functions to read, either one by one or a predefined amount, in both cases, it's unrelated to the end of a line, so you need the C parsing functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino cannot read data on the PC.

Instead the PC has to send the data to the Arduino, and the Arduino has to parse (interpret) that data.

You need two things:

1. A piece of software running on the PC that sends the file contents to the Arduino over serial
2. Software on the Arduino that accepts the stream of data coming in over the serial port and does something with it.

It is no different to handling commands that are manually typed by someone using the Serial Monitor - it's just they tend to come in a lot faster when being sent by the PC from a file.